# Xcode 7 - Cocoapod not importing

Tags: xcode, import, dependencies, cocoapods, beta

i am using Xcode 7 Beta3.

I tried to include one dependency, so this is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Test' do

pod 'Alamofire', '1.2.3'

end

target 'TestTests' do

end

target 'TestUITests' do

end
```

But when i import this class:

```
import Alamofire
```

i get:

```
No such module Alamofire
```

Anybody had this issue before?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Why are you using an old beta? Even if it isn't related I'd update it.

Comment: You should be using the Swift 2.0 branch of Alamofire:
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'

Comment: @ Felipe Cypriano how to do update my Beta3? @ Peter Willsey didnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

I ran into issues where Xcode 7 Beta 5 (7.1)(newest at the time) mixed with a Podfile would not recognize any of the pods I wanted to import.

Cocoapods updated to fix these issues.

```
[sudo] gem update cocoapods
```

Once that was up to date, I checked the git repositories that were included in my Podfile to see if any of them had Swift 2 branches.

After adding the `:branch => 'swift-2'` to the Podfile for the pod I am using, I was able to make the error in Xcode go away, and import the module.

Based on the comments on your question, Alamofire does have this branch and you should use that.

Run `pod update` on your project after saving your Podfile.